# Ionic Storage get not setting a public var

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic2

I am trying to set the token i have stored in the storage module of Ionic, to a public variable so i can call it later in the file, however when i try and set it and then call the variable from a different function i get a undefined error

code

```
import {HttpClient, HttpHeaders} from '@angular/common/http';
import {Component, Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import { Storage } from "@ionic/storage";
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

@Injectable()
@Component({
 providers: [HttpClient]
})
export class DataProvider {
 public token:string;

constructor(public http: HttpClient, public storage: Storage) {
}

 authToken(){
  console.log('token function')
  this.storage.get('token').then((val) => {
   this.token = val;
   console.log(this.token);
  });
 }

 getsomething(){
  let headers = new HttpHeaders();
  headers = headers.set('Content-Type', 'application/json');
  this.authToken();
  console.log(this.token);
 }

}
```

Comment: Show us the code where you're setting your token, also does your `console.log(this.token)` logs the token?

Comment: no that is what is giving the undefined error, however if i can call `console.log(this.token)` within the authToken function it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need `authToken()` to return a promise, since it's asynchronous your `getSomething()` will execute `authToken()` and will not wait for it to finish to execute the following `console.log(this.token)`, that's why it's coming as undefined. There's a couple ways you can work this out:

1 - Just get your token inside of your `getsomething()`

```
getsomething(){
  let headers = new HttpHeaders();
  headers = headers.set('Content-Type', 'application/json');
  this.storage.get('token').then((val) => {
    this.token = val;
    console.log(this.token);
    // THE REMAINING CODE YOU NEED TO EXECUTE
  });
}
```

2 - `authToken()` returns a promise

```
authToken = (): Promise<any> => {
  console.log('token function')
  return new Promise<any>(res => {
    this.storage.get('token').then((val) => {
      this.token = val;
      console.log(this.token);
      res(val);
    });
  });
}

getsomething(){
  let headers = new HttpHeaders();
  headers = headers.set('Content-Type', 'application/json');
  this.authToken().then(res => {
    console.log(this.token);
  });
}
```

3 - Get your token in your constructor (if you've already saved it before)

```
constructor(public storage: Storage){
  this.storage.get('token').then((val) => {
    this.token = val;
      console.log(this.token);
  });
}
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

It will be because the token is being read from storage using a promise, so when read in `authToken` the promise has resolved, but in `getsomething` you are trying to log the token before it has been set in the promise.

To be sure you have the token in `getsomething` you will need to return the promise from authToken

```
authToken(){
  console.log('token function')
  return this.storage.get('token').then((val) => {
   this.token = val;
   console.log(this.token);
  });
 }

getsomething(){
  let headers = new HttpHeaders();
  headers = headers.set('Content-Type', 'application/json');
  this.authToken().then(() => {
    console.log(this.token);
  })
 }
```